# How to Check first letter of an input with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform a simple javascript validation that checks the user input to see if the value's first letter is between A-F meaning, the first character in the string must be between A to F. Any idea of how i can accomplish this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please change your title like checking first letter or something like that.Now it is very generic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expression.. Something like:

```
function validateInput(input) {
   var re = /^[A-F].*/;
   return re.test(input);
}
```

For reference see [JavaScript RegExp Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

UPDATE: Use `/^[a-f].*/i` if you also accept lowercase letters.

Comment: The value can be boy for example. I just want to validate the first index of the values and not the entire values

Comment: if wont match 'boy', it needs to be ``/^[a-f]/i`` or one of the other ways to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Well, that's right. According to OP I understood that he wants just capital letters. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why JS/jQ?

```
<style>
    input:valid +p { display:none }
    input:invalid +p { display:block }
</style>

<form>
    <input type="text" pattern="^[a-fA-F].*" required ></input>
    <p>Must be provided and first letter should be between letter A and F.</p>
</form>
```

Comment: So they can be instant feedback. Most clients will not understand the html5 way

Comment: Use CSS for instant feedback, example updated. And we're up to 60% availability, although IE9 and Safari Mobile scupper it.http://caniuse.com/#compare=and_chr+0

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = 'test'

if (value >= 'A' && value <= 'F') {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes - if you need it to be case insensitive, you should cast your string to the same case you are comparing to, for example: `if (value.toUpperCase() >= 'A' ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try `indexOf()`

```
if(['A','B','C','D','E','F'].indexOf(youFirstChar) != -1){
 //found letter
}
```

Comment: This check for only the first letter but does not proceed if the other characters are not matching the letters in the arrey.